# I'm getting no such table <table name> error when i retrieve the data from sqlite? (Python 3.x)

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

```
import sqlite3 
import pandas as pd
a=sqlite3.connect('database.sqlite')
b=pd.read_sql_query(''' SELECT * FROM Reviews ''',a)
```

Am I retrieving my data in a wrong way?  Please help me out! Whereas ,'Reviews' is name of the table and 'database.sqlite' is name of the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is rather clear. Do you have a SQLitebrowser or another GUI tool ? Does that query run successfully if you execute it in some tool ?

What I think is that you have a path problem.

This statement:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect("database.db")
```

creates a new database (probably in the current application directory) if the file doesn't already exist. So I suspect that you created another DB with the same file name but in another directory. And indeed that new DB is therefore empty.

Fix: provide the full path to your database.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I don't know how, it didn't work even after copying the whole path

Comment: It worked! I copied that path incorrectly! I'm sorry for the inconvenience!! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are providing the wrong extension. It should be a .db file.

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect("database.db")
df = pd.read_sql_query('''SELECT * FROM Reviews;''', conn)
df
```

Comment: I'm sorry but it's still showing the same error because I've imported sqlite3 directly, instead of renaming it. For eg: If I imported sqlite3 as  ' import sqlite as db' ,then only I should add '.db' extension. So, it doesn't make any difference though

Comment: The extension does not matter. What needs to be entered is the exact file name.